# schedule the sending of an email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-email

I need to send an email 3 months after the client registered, I am using the gem exchange program, for now I send an email when the client registers, but I need to do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some kind of gem to do cron jobs, like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever). Or just use regular linux cron to run your script directly, and then program it to run every day.

And then the script to check when users registered:

```
User.where(sent_email: false).each do |user|
    if user.registered_date + 3.months < Time.now
        #send email
        user.update(sent_email:true)
    end
end
```

Comment: Don't forget to flag users you've sent so you don't send them an email every single run, forever.

Comment: Better to add the date condition as an SQL query as less expensive.

Comment: @PaulByrne yeah yeah, it was just to give an idea, the rest is with OP. :)